# Longitud del nombre más largo dentro de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Tengo el siguiente código que toma como parámetro una lista como la descrita y devuelva la longitud del nombre más largo y quería saber porque en ciertas pruebas que realizo se me cumple y en otras no. El programa solo me fallaen estas dos pruebas de 8 que realicé.

**Pruebas en las que falla:**

```
input: ['John','Paul','Christopher','Peter'] 
output esperado: 11
Devuelve: 5

input: ['Max','Kate','Fred']
output esperado: 4
Devuelve: 3
```

**Código:**

```
import functions

names = ['Max','Kate','Fred']
length = functions.longest(names)
print("El nombre más largo tiene longitud", length)


def longest(names):
    longitud = len(max(names))  
    return longitud
```

Answer (score 2):

La función `max` al aplicarla a textos creo que te devuelve el ultimo ordenados alfabeticamente, por eso en el primer caso es Peter (5) y en el segundo Max (3)

Prueba con `len(max(names, key=len))`

Comment: Gracias, pero que función tiene (key) ya que nunca lo he visto

Comment: @Chen Es un parámetro de la función max, por otro lado te recomiendo colocar titulos más descritivos de tu problema, decir "PLZ AYUDA; HELP; ETC" no ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Tambien lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```
def largestNameOfArray(names):

    print("Lista original : " + str(names))
    mayor = max(names, key = len)
    print(f"De la lista, el nombre de mayor longitud es : {mayor}")

names = ['John','Paul','Christopher','Peter'] 
length = largestNameOfArray( names )
```